# Filtering Elastic Search GET Request

Tags: php, elasticsearch, guzzle

i want to get data from my elasticsearch via GET request. I use the _search endpoint. A simple query is working correct like ?q=id:5.

I need to filter for results within the last 24 hours. I cant find a solution to do ist with a simple get request.

**Edit**
I cant found anything in the api documentation for Uri Query about filtering. Ich changed to POST method and json request data. it works like a charme.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using GET request by passing the parameters in the `q=...` parameter of the [URI search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html). The `q=...` parameter uses the same [query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) as the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

So if you need to filter your documents within the past 24 hours, you can achieve it using a [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges) like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?q=id:5 AND date:[now-24h TO now]'
```